# An inequality with plenty of summations.

Tags: inequality, summation, muirhead-inequality

I found a question, but was unable to solve it. The question is:

Let *k* be a positive integer, and let $x_1, x_2, ..., x_n$ be positive real numbers. Prove that
$$\left(\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{1+x_i}\right)\left(\sum_{i=1}^n x_i\right)\le\left(\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{x_i^{k+1}}{1+x_i}\right)\left(\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{x_i^k}\right) .$$
I tried if I could somehow use rearrangement inequality but due to the powers, I was unable to apply it. Please suggest some method to solve this.

Comment: Have you proved it for any small values of $k$?

Comment: @MichaelBurr I just tried for k=1. I realised I was making a mistake, but now I managed to solve it. Thank you for the suggestion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, without loss of generality, let us renumber the reals in ascending order, i.e. $x_0 \le x_1 \le \cdots \le x_n$.

Then, write the question as
$$
\sum_{i,j=0}^n \frac{x_j}{1+x_i}\le
\sum_{i,j=0}^n \frac{x_j}{1+x_i} \Big[\frac{x_i}{x_j}\Big]^{k+1}
$$
Let us call $w_{i,j} = \Big[\frac{x_i}{x_j}\Big]^{k+1}$.
The diagonal terms equal, so this can be written
$$
\sum_{i>j} (\frac{x_j}{1+x_i} + \frac{x_i}{1+x_j})\le
\sum_{i>j}  (w_{i,j} \frac{x_j}{1+x_i} + \frac{1}{w_{i,j}}\frac{x_i}{1+x_j})
$$
or
$$
\sum_{i>j}  \frac{ x_j (1+x_j) +   x_i (1+x_i)}{(1+x_i)(1+x_j)} \le \sum_{i>j}  \frac{w_{i,j} x_j (1+x_j) +  \frac{1}{w_{i,j}} x_i (1+x_i)}{(1+x_i)(1+x_j)} 
$$
We can now inspect this for each term in the sum. If we can show the inequality for each term we are done. This reads:
$$x_j (1+x_j) +   x_i (1+x_i) \le w_{i,j} x_j (1+x_j) +  \frac{1}{w_{i,j}} x_i (1+x_i)$$
which again is true if the two inequalities hold:
$$x_j + x_i  \le w_{i,j} x_j  + \frac{1}{w_{i,j}} x_i \\
x_j^2 + x_i^2  \le w_{i,j} x_j^2  + \frac{1}{w_{i,j}} x_i^2 $$
Now these inequalities are of the form
$a + b \le a w + b \frac1w $. When do they hold? Some simple equivalences: let $c = b/a \ge 1$ (see below that indeed $c \ge 1$), then
$$
a + b \le a w + b \frac1w \\
 \leftrightarrow c + 1\le w + c \frac1w\\
 \leftrightarrow 0 \le w^2 - (c + 1)w + c\\
 \leftrightarrow 0 \le (w- \frac12 (c + 1))^2 - \frac14 (c + 1)^2  + c\\
\leftrightarrow \frac14 (c - 1)^2   \le (w- \frac12 (c + 1))^2  \\
\leftrightarrow \frac12 (c - 1) + \frac12 (c + 1)   \le w \\
\leftrightarrow c   \le w \\
$$
Hence we need, reinstating the variables:
$$x_j + x_i  \le w_{i,j} x_j  + \frac{1}{w_{i,j}} x_i \\
\leftrightarrow  c = \frac{x_i}{x_j} \le w_{i,j} = \Big[\frac{x_i}{x_j}\Big]^{k+1} $$
which is true for all $k \ge 0$, since $c\ge 1 $ or $x_i \ge x_j$, as we consider the sum $\sum_{i>j} $ and the reals are numbered in ascending order.

Likewise, the second inequality is:
$$x_j^2 + x_i^2  \le w_{i,j} x_j^2  + \frac{1}{w_{i,j}} x_i^2 \\
\leftrightarrow  \frac{x_i^2}{x_j^2} \le w_{i,j} = \Big[\frac{x_i}{x_j}\Big]^{k+1} $$
which is true for all $k \ge 1$. Hence $k \ge 1$ is the stricter condition, which is given since the $k$ are positive integers. $ \qquad \Box$

Answer (score 2):

By Muirhead we obtain: $$\sum \frac{x_i^{k+1}}{1+x_i}\sum\frac{1}{x_i^k}-\sum\frac{1}{1+x_i}\sum x_i=$$
$$=\frac{1}{4}\sum_{i\neq j}\left(\frac{x_i^{k+1}}{(1+x_i)x_j^k}+\frac{x_j^{k+1}}{(1+x_j)x_i^k}-\frac{x_i}{1+x_j}-\frac{x_j}{1+x_i}\right)=$$
$$=\frac{1}{4}\sum_{i\neq j}\frac{x_i^{2k+1}(1+x_j)+x_j^{2k+1}(1+x_i)-x_i^kx_j^k(x_i+x_j+x_i^2+x_j^2)}{(1+x_i)(1+x_j)x_i^kx_j^k}=$$
$$=\frac{1}{4}\sum_{i\neq j}\tfrac{\left(x_i^{2k+1}+x_j^{2k+1}-x_i^{k+1}x_j^k-x_i^kx_j^{k+1}\right)+\left(x_i^{2k+1}x_j+x_j^{2k+1}x_i-x_i^{k+2}x_j^k-x_i^kx_j^{k+2}\right)}{(1+x_i)(1+x_j)x_i^kx_j^k}\geq0.$$